# AS3 TextField setting top margin of text because some chars are cutted out

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textfield, margin

I am trying to figure out why some letters (like the norwegian Å (Å)) are cutted out in the middle of the top "o":

[image]

My code is this:

```
        var titleFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        titleFormat.size = textSize;
           // this is embedded font, and exported for action script, declared
        titleFormat.font = myFontBold.fontName;
        titleFormat.bold = true;
        titleFormat.color = parseInt("0x"+fontColor,16);

        var titleText:TextField = new TextField();
        titleText.defaultTextFormat = titleFormat;
        titleText.embedFonts = true;            
        titleText.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
        titleText.text = "Å"+text;
        addChild(titleText);

        titleText.selectable = false;           
        titleText.wordWrap = true;          
        titleText.width = maskImg.width - 80;           
          // this should autosize to fit all text, but it doesn't the top of text
        titleText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        titleText.x = x;
        titleText.y = y;
```

So, i have tried different things like setting height hardcoded and bigger than text, but top us cutted again, i have tried with css but no success. Anyone has idea why the letter is not showed fully and why if i zoom in the swf (2-3 zoom ins) it shows up normal (and what i try to achieve) like this:

[image]

I think it has to do with the topMargin, but unfortunately i didn't find something like that in as3 documentation.

Comment: In Flex styles there is `paddingTop`, but you have pure TextField. This can be text measuring bug - letter goes out of the box. You might try to render text to bitmap and show the bitmap (it can be cut too, but maybe there is matrix scale/font size combination that avoids it.)

Comment: Yes, i have tried that too, but as you said it too cached the bitmap without the top. I think this is probably a bug that needs to be fixed in some future flash versions, or add a new margins (now its only leftMargin and rightMargin, probably this needs topMargin and bottomMargin, so that we are able to fix these things by setting the text more inside)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but I tested the following complete, self contained code with the Verdana font, not embedded and it works fine. Perhaps the font you are embedding has a problem itself, or the embedding is causing a problem for some reason?

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.*;

    public class TestText extends MovieClip {

        public function TestText() {

            var textSize = 20;

            var titleFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            titleFormat.size = textSize;
            titleFormat.font = "Verdana";
            titleFormat.color = 0xFF0000;

            var titleText:TextField = new TextField();
            titleText.defaultTextFormat = titleFormat;          
            titleText.text = "Åbcdefg";
            titleText.backgroundColor = 0x000000;
            titleText.background = true;
            addChild(titleText);

            titleText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            titleText.selectable = false;           
            titleText.wordWrap = true;          
            titleText.width = 200;    

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing it to Verdana worked, so its probably the font as you suggested. But then, i noticed when not using embedding, the "o" is not visible at all on that font, and embedding it it shows it in half (see the first image).

So, i think that the font is the cause for this, but flash should have a way to handle these kinds of fonts, or at least a way to fix it with topMargin and bottomMargin.